# Small MVVM state editor architecture

Tags: wpf, mvvm, model, viewmodel

I wanna write a small state editor.
It should use the MVVM pattern.

```
 /-------------\    Transition   /-------------\
 |   State 1   |-----------------|   State 2   |
 \-------------/                 \-------------/
```

So my question is how the architecture should look like.

My first thoughts were that I have

- state model
- state viewmodel
- satte view
- transition model
- transition viewmodel
- transition view
- main view with canvas

But how do I have to connect these things? 
Should I create a mainViewModel which holds a ObservableCollection with StateViews and on with TransitionViews?
And is it enough to have only one canvas for both transitoins and states?

Comment: Why not just use the purpose built [`VisualStateManager` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager(v=vs.110).aspx)? Also, your question is [primarily opinion based](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and so not a good fit for this website. As such, I have voted to close it.

Comment: Have a look at a ViewModelLocator, and galasoft MVVM light forinstance(avaliable through nuget).